# Error using integral (line 85): A and B must be floating-point scalars

Tags: matlab, debugging, integral, mle

I have the following code that I wish to estimate the parameters of a custom distribution using MATLAB's function `mle()`. [For more details on the distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56522903/4930944).

The main code is:

```
x           =  [0   0   0   0   0.000649967501624919    0.00569971501424929 0.0251487425628719  0.0693465326733663  0.155342232888356   0.284835758212089   0.458277086145693   0.658567071646418   0.908404579771011   1.17284135793210    1.43977801109945    1.71951402429879    1.98925053747313    2.27553622318884    2.57147142642868    2.80390980450977    3.03829808509575    3.26583670816459    3.45642717864107    3.65106744662767    3.81950902454877    3.98275086245688    4.11259437028149    4.24683765811709    4.35043247837608    4.43832808359582    4.58427078646068    4.62286885655717    4.68361581920904    4.75686215689216    4.80245987700615    4.84005799710015    4.86280685965702    4.91675416229189    4.92725363731813    4.90890455477226    4.96570171491425    4.92315384230789    4.95355232238388    4.92790360481976    4.93135343232838    4.90310484475776    4.90885455727214    4.86765661716914    4.85490725463727    4.81940902954852    4.81450927453627    4.78621068946553    4.74206289685516    4.71791410429479    4.69961501924904    4.65706714664267    4.63611819409030    4.60176991150443    4.57512124393780    4.53507324633768    4.48252587370631    4.47062646867657    4.43127843607820    4.39963001849908    4.37598120093995    4.29548522573871    4.31033448327584    4.21708914554272    4.21913904304785    4.18669066546673    4.16719164041798    4.09774511274436    4.07989600519974    4.02869856507175    3.98485075746213    3.95785210739463    3.93945302734863    3.90240487975601    3.87025648717564    3.81185940702965    3.78461076946153    3.74091295435228    3.71666416679166    3.67276636168192    3.65846707664617    3.61361931903405    3.58712064396780    3.55452227388631    3.53082345882706    3.49197540122994    3.48582570871456    3.46512674366282    3.41227938603070    3.36278186090695    3.35528223588821    3.31238438078096    3.27213639318034    3.23863806809660    3.24173791310434    3.19339033048348    3.20118994050298    3.16489175541223    3.10739463026849    3.09484525773711    3.08094595270237    3.02129893505325    3.02309884505775    2.99375031248438    2.95765211739413    2.93230338483076    2.89560521973901    2.87805609719514    2.85440727963602    2.82285885705715    2.80175991200440    2.79091045447728    2.73901304934753    2.72701364931753    2.73441327933603    2.71646417679116    2.68236588170592    2.65551722413879    2.63356832158392    2.60361981900905    2.58147092645368    2.57697115144243    2.54287285635718    2.53502324883756    2.47702614869257    2.50387480625969    2.46487675616219    2.45722713864307    2.42707864606770    2.41762911854407    2.39823008849558    2.38708064596770    2.34058297085146    2.35613219339033    2.32123393830309    2.30503474826259    2.27613619319034    2.27248637568122    2.25113744312784    2.24908754562272    2.22703864806760    2.20583970801460    2.17244137793110    2.15709214539273    2.16469176541173    2.12139393030348    2.12809359532023    2.11389430528474    2.09774511274436    2.07629618519074    2.07459627018649    2.05394730263487    2.04724763761812    2.01684915754212    2.01684915754212    2.00409979501025    1.98955052247388    1.96540172991350    1.95890205489726    1.93035348232588    1.92295385230738    1.90605469726514    1.89785510724464    1.87070646467677    1.88000599970002    1.86295685215739    1.84420778961052    1.82510874456277    1.80480975951202    1.80785960701965    1.80870956452177    1.77581120943953    1.76771161441928    1.77131143442828    1.76636168191590    1.75081245937703    1.73156342182891    1.69876506174691    1.70836458177091    1.70376481175941    1.67196640167992    1.68101594920254    1.66586670666467    1.66061696915154    1.64296785160742    1.63291835408230    1.62506874656267    1.62516874156292    1.60556972151392    1.59007049647518    1.59187040647968    1.57947102644868    1.57577121143943    1.54527273636318    1.57237138143093    1.54637268136593    1.54802259887006    1.50492475376231    1.52077396130193    1.50417479126044    1.50162491875406    1.50062496875156    1.48957552122394    1.47997600119994    1.47027648617569    1.44452777361132    1.45407729613519    1.44272786360682    1.43247837608120    1.41657917104145    1.40787960601970    1.39323033848308    1.40282985850707    1.39403029848508    1.38233088345583    1.37888105594720    1.37943102844858    1.36183190840458    1.34808259587021    1.34503274836258    1.33703314834258    1.33308334583271    1.32253387330633    1.32698365081746    1.29963501824909    1.30758462076896    1.29103544822759    1.29473526323684    1.27413629318534    1.26858657067147    1.27888605569722    1.26063696815159    1.27863606819659    1.25168741562922    1.23913804309785    1.24788760561972    1.22308884555772    1.24198790060497    1.22133893305335    1.20678966051697    1.20098995050247    1.20343982800860    1.18779061046948    1.19024048797560    1.17194140292985    1.17369131543423    1.16869156542173    1.15814209289536    1.15429228538573    1.15904204789761    1.12774361281936    1.15344232788361    1.13744312784361    1.12909354532273    1.12479376031198    1.11099445027749    1.11469426528674    1.11064446777661    1.10464476776161    1.10309484525774    1.10689465526724    1.07654617269137    1.07884605769712    1.07359632018399    1.06864656767162    1.07544622768862    1.06689665516724    1.04884755762212    1.06164691765412    1.04979751012449    1.04529773511324    1.02839858007100    1.03634818259087    1.01709914504275    1.02089895505225    1.01024948752562    1.01549922503875    1.01319934003300    1.01404929753512    1.00839958002100    0.995400229988501   0.989850507474626   0.978801059947003   0.977551122443878   0.980450977451127   0.975451227438628   0.969201539923004   0.964151792410380   0.964601769911504   0.958802059897005   0.955702214889256   0.948602569871506   0.960751962401880   0.941352932353382   0.928653567321634   0.949002549872506   0.937053147342633   0.913854307284636   0.916204189790510   0.915454227288636   0.902604869756512   0.909454527273636   0.895505224738763   0.898355082245888   0.894455277236138   0.902454877256137   0.883705814709265   0.888405579721014   0.876356182190891   0.881555922203890   0.878156092195390   0.868456577171141   0.870406479676016   0.863906804659767   0.862456877156142   0.858757062146893   0.851307434628269   0.851107444627769   0.833908304584771   0.843507824608770   0.831708414579271   0.836858157092145   0.829058547072646   0.828508574571272   0.822908854557272   0.820508974551273   0.815559222038898   0.819709014549273   0.809609519524024   0.813409329533523   0.800759962001900   0.806609669516524   0.806959652017399   0.792260386980651   0.787660616969152   0.783810809459527   0.794960251987401   0.771061446927654   0.788910554472276   0.789510524473776   0.763061846907655   0.776761161941903   0.767561621918904   0.773611319434028   0.750262486875656   0.765811709414529   0.765911704414779   0.748012599370032   0.741612919354032   0.757312134393280   0.752612369381531   0.741362931853407   0.742212889355532   0.741912904354782   0.743162841857907   0.732963351832408   0.732813359332033   0.733363331833408   0.721913904304785   0.716664166791661   0.726713664316784   0.709764511774411   0.700064996750163   0.710764461776911   0.717664116794160   0.707314634268287   0.707114644267787   0.705614719264037   0.709164541772911   0.696665166741663   0.680765961701915   0.686715664216789   0.694465276736163   0.683015849207540   0.681715914204290   0.694465276736163   0.688615569221539   0.680665966701665   0.672316384180791   0.672866356682166   0.656517174141293   0.665316734163292   0.671566421678916   0.666266686665667   0.652917354132293   0.663366831658417   0.651917404129794   0.663816809159542   0.661366931653417   0.647017649117544   0.655167241637918   0.647867606619669   0.636918154092295   0.645467726613669   0.633118344082796   0.640217989100545   0.634668266586671   0.618669066546673   0.635068246587671   0.632568371581421   0.623118844057797   0.623868806559672   0.623718814059297   0.621368931553422   0.623768811559422   0.608419579021049   0.616019199040048   0.609869506524674   0.606569671516424   0.614019299035048   0.610269486525674   0.596520173991300   0.595570221488926   0.593270336483176   0.596670166491675   0.598470076496175   0.597770111494425   0.593720313984301   0.592770361481926   0.585420728963552   0.580870956452177   0.584120793960302   0.580270986450677   0.577971101444928   0.579021048947553   0.572821358932053   0.585970701464927   0.572921353932303   0.567071646417679   0.569971501424929   0.571271436428179   0.568421578921054   0.567421628918554   0.569521523923804   0.563721813909305   0.558772061396930   0.562171891405430   0.557872106394680   0.549072546372681   0.558722063896805   0.536973151342433   0.561021948902555   0.544172791360432   0.552122393880306   0.553072346382681   0.546222688865557   0.551472426378681   0.540772961351932   0.541122943852807   0.542772861356932   0.530323483825809   0.526023698815059   0.529273536323184   0.524573771311435   0.525923703814809   0.524923753812309   0.516474176291185   0.527273636318184   0.527723613819309   0.518424078796060   0.517874106294685   0.516074196290186   0.517924103794810   0.523173841307935   0.514474276286186   0.513174341282936   0.498875056247188   0.518024098795060   0.507924603769812   0.505524723763812   0.507174641267937   0.502874856257187   0.502624868756562   0.500624968751562   0.510824458777061   0.490925453727314   0.492675366231688   0.489925503724814   0.478126093695315   0.485775711214439   0.491775411229439   0.489925503724814   0.491325433728314   0.487225638718064   0.485725713714314   0.485675716214189   0.477676116194190   0.483875806209690   0.478026098695065   0.470176491175441   0.471926403679816   0.483625818709065   0.469376531173441   0.474026298685066   0.467826608669567   0.462426878656067];

Censored    =  ones(1,size(x,2));% 
custpdf     =  @eval_custpdf;
custcdf     =  @eval_custcdf;
phat        =  mle(x,'pdf', custpdf,'cdf', custcdf,'start',[1 0.1 0.3 0.1 0.01 -0.3],...
               'lowerbound',[0 0 0 0 0 -inf],'upperbound',[inf inf inf inf inf inf],'Censoring',Censored);

% Cheking how close the estimated PDF and CDF match with those from the data x
t   =  0.001:0.001:0.5;
figure();
plot(t,x);hold on
plot(t,custpdf(t, phat(1), phat(2), phat(3), phat(4), phat(5), phat(6))) 

figure();
plot(t,cumsum(x)./sum(x));hold on
plot(t,custcdf(t, phat(1), phat(2), phat(3), phat(4), phat(5), phat(6)))
```

The functions are:

```
function out = eval_custpdf(x,myalpha,mybeta,mytheta,a,b,c)
  first_integral      =  integral(@(x) eval_K(x,a,b,c),0,1).^-1;
  theta_t_ratio       =  (mytheta./x);
  incomplete_gamma    =  igamma(myalpha,theta_t_ratio.^mybeta);
  n_gamma             =  gamma(myalpha);
  exponent_term       =  exp(-theta_t_ratio.^mybeta-(c.*(incomplete_gamma./n_gamma)));


  numerator   =  first_integral.* mybeta.*incomplete_gamma.^(a-1).*...
               theta_t_ratio.^(myalpha*mybeta+1).*exponent_term;
  denominator =  mytheta.* n_gamma.^(a+b-1).* (n_gamma-incomplete_gamma.^mybeta).^(1-b);

  out         =  numerator./denominator;
end

function out = eval_custcdf(x,myalpha,mybeta,mytheta,a,b,c)
  first_integral      =  integral(@(x) eval_K(x,a,b,c),0,1).^-1;
  theta_t_ratio       =  (mytheta./x);
  incomplete_gamma    =  igamma(myalpha,theta_t_ratio.^mybeta);
  n_gamma             =  gamma(myalpha);
  second_integral     =  integral(@(x) eval_K(x,a,b,c),0, incomplete_gamma.^mybeta./n_gamma);
                                                         % |<----- PROBLEMATIC LINE ----->|

  out     =  first_integral*second_integral;

end    

function out = eval_K(x,a,b,c)

  out =  x.^(a-1).*(1-x).^(b-1).*exp(-c.*x);

end
```

The integral that is causing the problem is the second intergral in the function `eval_custcdf()` as its upper limit is an array (denoted by *PROBLEMATIC LINE*).

Is there a way to take a single value from the array `x` such that the upper limit remains a scalar? And then calculate the cdf such that the output of the cdf is an array? Using a `forloop`, maybe? But I cannot seem to figure how to implement that?

How can I work around this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer. But why do you create an anonymous function that call call the exact same function ? Also you should split your function into several lines, it's pretty hard to read your code.

Comment: @obchardon I tried to split the functions into several lines to improve readability. However, I am not sure how not to ` create an anonymous function that calls the exact same function`. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @obchardon I think I fixed it. Did I get rid of the redundant call now?

Comment: If you can sample your PDF, then `cdf = cumsum(pdf)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `eval_custcdf` is a function expected to return `1D array of length n` for
  a given `n` data input.
- I use a `for loop` to compute the output for a given input, then
  return the whole array as output of `eval_custcdf`

**I passed the input array elements one at a time**

---

This is how `eval_custcdf` may look like

```
function out = eval_custcdf(x,myalpha,mybeta,mytheta,a,b,c)
    out = zeros(size(x));
    for i = 1: length(x)
          first_integral      =  integral(@(w) eval_K(w,a,b,c),0,1).^-1;
          theta_t_ratio       =  (mytheta./x(i));
          incomplete_gamma    =  igamma(myalpha,theta_t_ratio.^mybeta);
          n_gamma             =  gamma(myalpha);
          second_integral     =  integral(@(w) eval_K(w,a,b,c),0, incomplete_gamma.^mybeta./n_gamma);

          out(i) = first_integral*second_integral;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much once again, Adam. That works well. Now I need to figure out a way to find the good guess for the initial start points of the parameters.